# w3c error for end tag for element "P" which is not open

Tags: w3c, w3c-validation

I've been trying to validate some basic html pages on my site and keep getting the error code; end tag for element "P" which is not open. I'm sure there is something very basic wrong with either my Doc Type or my character set. Here's what the beginning of the page looks like...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><HTML>  
<HEAD>
<title>Michigan Adoption photographer - MI Wedding Photographer - Baby            Shower Gift</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgCOLOR="#868682" VLINK="#ffffff" ALINK="#3399ff" LINK="#ffffff">


<P><CENTER><B><i><FONT COLOR="#ffffff" SIZE="+3" FACE="chicago">Celebrating An Adoption!</FONT></i></B></CENTER></p>
<P><CENTER><B><FONT COLOR="#898989" SIZE="+1" FACE="New York"><A HREF="contact.html"><IMG SRC="contactbutton.jpg" ALT="Contact information for Marci Curtis, phone numbers and e-mail address." BORDER="0" align=middle></A></font></b></center></p>
<BR>
<BR>
 <P><CENTER><IMG SRC="adoption1.jpg" ALT="Michigan family photos taken in natural Michigan settings" BORDER="2"></CENTER></p>


<BR>
<BR>

<p><center><IMG SRC="adoption2.jpg" BORDER="2" ALT="Michigan family photo taken in natural settings">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="adoption3.jpg" BORDER="2" ALT="Michigan photojournalist comes to your home for family photos"></CENTER></p>

<BR>
<P><CENTER><IMG SRC="adoption4.jpg" BORDER="2" ALT="Michigan family photos make a great baby shower gift"></CENTER></p>

<BR>
<P><CENTER><IMG SRC="adoption5.jpg" BORDER="2" ALT="Michigan family photography taken in natural settings">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="adoption6.jpg" BORDER="2" ALT="Michigan family portraiture taken in natural settings"></CENTER></p>
<BR>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use `<center>` inside `<p>`. Remove the `<center>` tags. Use CSS to center the contents of your `<p>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the w3c-validation, The p is case-sensitive, so the P and p is not paired. You should change the P to p in your "< P >" element.

Comment: Thanks so much Feng. I changed them all to be paired and I'm still getting the same number of errors and the same error messages. I really hoped it was going to be something so simple and easy to fix. Any other suggestions?